# Imports libraries dont stay on code

Tags: android-studio, import

When ever I start a new project to practice using Android Studio the following 
imports are added by default:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

As soon as I start adding another import to follow an example from a book or tutorial the whole new line disappears. If I add lines without the semicolon nothing happens. As soon as I begin adding the semicolons the new lines start disappearing. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudio auto "organizes" your imports. Just start adding your code and it will add the imports that you need. If you want to toggle this off, which I don't recommend, it's in: Preferences -> Editor(Under IDE Settings) -> General -> Auto Import

Comment: Thank you so much, I already tried it and yes it does exactly what you said! You just made my life a bit easier to learn Android Studio.